# Access array of dictionaries Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I need to access the work data which is inside an array of dictionaries and I'm a little bit confuse with this. I'm using swift 3. Some one can give-me some piece of coding to make it done?

I'm using this

```
let work: NSArray! = fbData.value(forKey: "work") as! NSArray
            if let position: NSArray = work[0] as! NSArray {
                let positionName: String = position.value(forKey: "name") as! String
                self.userWorkExpLabel.text = "\(positionName)" as String
            }
```

but I'm having this answer:
Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x1106c7288) to 'NSArray' (0x1106c6e28).

there's the API

```
{
"work": [
{
  "employer": {
    "id": "93643283467",
    "name": "Oracast"
  },
  "location": {
    "id": "111983945494775",
    "name": "Calgary, Alberta"
  },
  "position": {
    "id": "146883511988628",
    "name": "Mobile Developer"
  },
  "start_date": "2017-04-30",
  "id": "1446626725564198"
}
],
```

---

Ok guys. I tried what you posted and what I have now is something like this:

a structs class:

```
import Foundation

struct Worker{
let employer: Employer
let location: Location
let position: Position
let startDate:String
let id: String

init?(fromDict dict: Dictionary<String, Any>){
    guard let employer = Employer(fromDict: dict["employer"] as? Dictionary<String, String>),
        let location = Location(fromDict: dict["location"] as? Dictionary<String, String>),
        let position = Position(fromDict: dict["position"] as? Dictionary<String, String>),
        let startDate = dict["start_date"] as? String,
        let id = dict["id"] as? String else {
            return nil
    }

    self.employer = employer
    self.location = location
    self.position = position
    self.startDate = startDate
    self.id = id
}

}

struct Employer{
let id: String
let name: String

init?(fromDict dict:Dictionary<String, String>?){
    guard let id = dict?["id"],
        let name = dict?["name"] else{
            return nil
    }

    self.id = id
    self.name = name
 }
 }

struct Location {
let id:String
let name:String

init?(fromDict dict:Dictionary<String, String>?) {
    guard let id = dict?["id"],
        let name = dict?["name"] else {
        return nil
    }
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
}
}

struct Position {
let id:String
let name:String

init?(fromDict dict:Dictionary<String, String>?) {
    guard let id = dict?["id"],
        let name = dict?["name"] else {
        return nil
    }
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
}
}
```

Ive created a class called facebookGraphRequest.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKShareKit

class facebookGraphRequest: NSObject {

class func graphRequestWork(completion: @escaping(_ error: Error?, _ facebookUserWork: Worker)-> Void){
    if ((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){
    let parameters = ["fields": "name, picture.width(198).height(198), location{location}, work{employer}, education, about, id"]

        let graphRequest: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters)
        graphRequest.start { (connection, result, error) in

            if ((error) != nil ){
                print(error!)
            }else {
                print(result!)

                func workersArray(data:Dictionary<String, Any>)->[Worker]?{
                    guard let arrayOfDict = data["work"] as? Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> else {
                        return nil
                    }

                    return arrayOfDict.flatMap({ Worker(fromDict: $0)})
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

and I'm calling this data inside the viewController with:

```
func facebookLogin(){
    facebookGraphRequest.graphRequestWork { (error: Error?, facebookUserWork: Worker) in

        self.userNameJobPositionLabel.text = "\(facebookUserWork.position)"
        self.companyNameLabel.text = "\(facebookUserWork.employer)"
    }
}
```

Somebody knows what's happening? There's nothing happening with the labels.

I thought this apis was easier than that. I'm really confused with this process... Sorry if it looks like stupid questions but I'm really messing my mind because of this things... I really need your help guys. My work depends on that :(

Comment: First, never use `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` in Swift unless you really have to.  Second, you have an array of dictionaries, so `work[0]` is a dictionary, not an array, which is why your forced downcast failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting with Swift 4 and going in the direction that @PuneetSharma demonstrated I found it's even easier when you use raw JSON text, `Codable`, and `JSONDecoder`:

```
import Foundation

// define the nested structures

struct Work: Codable {
  let work: [Worker]
}

struct Worker: Codable {
  let employer: Employer
  let location: Location
  let position: Position
  let startDate: String
  let id: String

  // needed a custom key for start_date
  enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case employer, location, position, startDate = "start_date", id
  }
}

struct Employer: Codable {
  let id: String
  let name: String
}

struct Location: Codable {
  let id: String
  let name: String
}

struct Position: Codable {
  let id: String
  let name: String
}

// turn the text into `Data` and then 
// decode as the outermost structure

if let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8),
  let work = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Work.self, from: jsonData) {
  print(work)
}
```

The result is a `Work` structure with all the data:

```
Work(work: [
  Model.Worker(employer : Model.Employer(id  : "93643283467",
                                         name: "Oracast"),
               location : Model.Location(id  : "111983945494775",
                                         name: "Calgary, Alberta"),
               position : Model.Position(id  : "146883511988628",
                                         name: "Mobile Developer"),
               startDate: "2017-04-30", 
               id       : "1446626725564198")
])
```

(I formatted the output a bit to clarify the structures produced.)

You get a lot of functionality for free just by using `Codable`. It's also simple to go the other way and produce JSON text from any of the structures.

Answer (score 1):

You should ideally introduce model classes like this:

```
struct Worker {
    let employer:Employer
    let location:Location
    let position:Position
    let startDate:String
    let id:String

    init?(fromDict dict:Dictionary<String, Any>) {
        guard let employer = Employer(fromDict: dict["employer"] as? Dictionary<String, String>), let location = Location(fromDict: dict["location"] as? Dictionary<String, String>), let position = Position(fromDict: dict["position"] as? Dictionary<String, String>), let startDate = dict["start_date"] as? String, let id = dict["id"] as? String else {
            return nil
        }

        self.employer = employer
        self.location = location
        self.position = position
        self.startDate = startDate
        self.id = id
    }
}

struct Employer {
    let id:String
    let name:String

    init?(fromDict dict:Dictionary<String, String>?) {
        guard let id = dict?["id"], let name = dict?["name"] else {
            return nil
        }
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct Location {
    let id:String
    let name:String

    init?(fromDict dict:Dictionary<String, String>?) {
        guard let id = dict?["id"], let name = dict?["name"] else {
            return nil
        }
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct Position {
    let id:String
    let name:String

    init?(fromDict dict:Dictionary<String, String>?) {
        guard let id = dict?["id"], let name = dict?["name"] else {
            return nil
        }
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Now, you can introduce a function like this:

```
func workersArray(data:Dictionary<String, Any>)->[Worker]?{
        guard let arrayOfDict = data["work"] as? Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> else {
            return nil
        }

        return arrayOfDict.flatMap({ Worker(fromDict: $0)})
    }
```

Comment: Looks clean. The only thing I'd add is something like `enum EmployerKey: String { case id, name }` so there's concrete strings to match the dictionary keys. Use them like `dict?[EmployerKey.name.rawValue]`

Comment: @ColGraff: I agree, that will wrap the hard-coded strings inside an enum in a nice way. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It really shines when you add in serialization, that way your keys match easily in both the serialization and deserialization code and minimize the amount of errors due to mistyping them.

Comment: Also, it can be made more compact by nesting in the class and making it like: `struct Employer { enum Keys: String { } }`

Comment: @ColGraff: Nested enums is what should be done. With Swift introduction of Encodable and Decodable protocols, the serialization is fun again :). The OP has already accepted another answer, so I am not editing this one but would definitely use nested enums in my project.

Comment: In fact, I completely forgot that a `struct` declared `Codable` automatically gains keys under `CodingKeys`. So skip the `enum` and just use  `struct Employer: Codable {...}` then you can do `CodingKeys.name.stringValue`

Comment: @ColGraff: Yeah but you may want to provide custom keys and nested enums is the way to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any] {
    if let workArray = json["work"] as? [[String: Any]] {
        if let dictWork = workArray.first {
            if let dictPosition = dictWork["position"] as?  [String: String] {
                print("position name : \(dictPosition["name"])")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's giving an error:  Cannot convert value of type '(_,_,_) throws -> ()' to expected arguments of type FBSDKGraphRequestHandler.

Comment: If you have a lot of nested `if let` statements you can make it simpler just by separating them with commas instead of nesting them.